# Java - Jackson JSON Library and ObjectMapper.readValue

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json data (patients.json):

```
{ 
    "A" : { 
        "name" : "Tom", 
        "age" : 12 
    }, 
    "B" : { 
        "name" : "Jim", 
        "age" : 54 
    } 
}
```

Using the Jackson JSON library, how can I get something like the following:

```
HashMap<String, ???> patients = objectMapper.readValue(new File("patients.json"), ???);

String Aname = patients.get("A").get("name");
int Aname = patients.get("A").get("age");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class to map your patients to;

```
private static class Patient {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("age")
    private int age;

    public Patient() { }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then read your json into it via jackson

```
HashMap<String, Patient> patients = objectMapper.readValue(new File("patients.json"), new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Patient>>() {});
Patient patientA = patients.get("A");
String patientAName = patientA.getName();
int pateintAAge = patientA.getAge();
```

Answer (score 4):

Deserialize your JSON into Jackson's JSON Object type, [`ObjectNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode.html). You can then traverse it as you see fit.

For example

```
ObjectNode patients = objectMapper.readValue(new File("test.json"), ObjectNode.class);
// you can check if it is actually an ObjectNode with JsonNode#isObject()
ObjectNode nodeA = (ObjectNode)patients.get("A");

String name = nodeA.get("name").asText();
int age = (int) nodeA.get("age").asLong();
```

Note that the methods `asXyz()` return default values if the target node cannot be converted to that type. You can check with the corresponding `isXyz()` methods before invoking them.